# discover bluetooth devices without devices that already i did paired with those

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

I want to discover Bluetooth devices without devices that already I have already paired. But my python script shows the Bluetooth device that are ON + the device sthat I have paired with. How I can filter just devices that are ON and ignore the paired devices from PC without deleting them.

This is my script

```py
import bluetooth
def search():
    devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(duration=1, lookup_names = True)
    return devices

if __name__=="__main__":
    while True:
        results = search()
        if (results!=None):
            for addr, name in results:
                print ("{0}".format(name))
                print ("{0}".format(addr))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this via [pybluez API](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez) which is not even under active development. If we look at the API you can set `flush_cache` to `False` to not the see previously discovered devices. But again it does show paired devices.

```
def discover_devices (duration=8, flush_cache=True, lookup_names=False,
                      lookup_class=False, device_id=-1, iac=IAC_GIAC):
```

But also below, I see that:

```
try:
    results = _bt.hci_inquiry (sock, duration=duration, flush_cache=True,
                               lookup_class=lookup_class, device_id=device_id,
                               iac=iac)
```

You might want to try setting this to a `False` and give it a shot.

I do not want to discover the paired devices is also seems not possible via D-BUS API. If we look at the [adapter-api.txt](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/blob/master/doc/adapter-api.txt) there is a `void SetDiscoveryFilter(dict filter)` method, but it does not do what you want.

Another workaround is using **DBUS API** to get the info of if the device is discovered or not then make some list if it is not paired, then you will have a nice list of unpaired devices. If your domain is Linux, you might want to check where cache is [kept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446918/bluez-showing-old-cached-data-on-dbus).